# All possible variants of zip in Python

Tags: python, list

For example, I have a code looks like this:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [4, 5]
```

How can I get something like this:

```
[(1,4), (1,5), (2,4), (2,5)]
```

Like function `zip` does, but with all possible variants. Or can't I?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You want [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = [4,5]
>>> list(itertools.product(a,b))
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
```

Answer (score 11):

If you're interested only in the result, then `itertools.product` is what you need (+1 to @DSM for this). However, if you're interested in the algorithm that generates something like this, it's called [recursive descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). The algorithm, in this case, would run as follows (I'm just going to print the results here for clarity):

```
def product(L, tmp=None):
    if tmp is None:
        tmp = []
    if L==[]:
        print tmp
    else:
        for i in L[0]:
            product(L[1:], tmp+[i])
```

Thus,

```
>>> product([[1,2], [4,5]])
[1, 4]
[1, 5]
[2, 4]
[2, 5]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I would modify this code to remove the mutable default variable. if this code is being used as an example to beginners, then it really should avoid these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this nicely with list comprehension, or better yet with a generator expression if you just need to iterate through the combinations.

Here's it is using list comprehension:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [4, 5]

[(i, j) for i in a for j in b]
```

And here with a generator expression:

```
for pair in ((i, j) for i in a for j in b):
    print(pair)
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't overlook the obvious:

```
out = []
for a in [1, 2]:
    for b in [4, 5]:
        out.append((a, b))
```

or list comprehensions:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [4, 5]
out = [(x, y) for x in a for y in b]
```

Both produce `out == [(1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5)]`