# Python find all the different choices from list of list

Tags: python, list, combinations

I want to get all the different choices from a list of lists in python. for example, take a list like,

```
list=[[a,b,c],[a,d,e]]
```

I just want to select choices from one at each list and get all the possible different selections.
so above list possible choices look like,

```
    [a,a]
    [a,d]
    [a,e]
    [b,a]
    [b,d]
    [b,e]
    [c,a]
    [c,d]
    [c,e]
```

without using any external library, how can I do this?

Comment: any effort you have tried ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All possible variants of zip in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907263/all-possible-variants-of-zip-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Easiest to implement with a recursive generator.

```
def yield_combos(lst):
    if lst:
        for el in lst[0]:
            for combo in yield_combos(lst[1:]):
                yield [el] + combo
    else:
        yield []


lst = [['a','b','c'], ['a','d','e']]
for combo in yield_combos(lst):
    print(combo)
```

If you prefer the output as a list, you can always convert it into one:

```
print(list(yield_combos(lst)))
```

Minor notes:

- I've called the variable `lst` where the question uses `list`; it's not a good idea to override a builtin, and in this case doing so would prevent the call to `list` from working.
- I've set some string values in the caller for sake of a self-contained program (the question had `a` in place of `'a'`, etc).

Comment: if I need to get all possible choices with a condition such as at it should include the first choice at least one list. Then I can use for big size list. can you tell me how can I do it using your code

Answer (score 1):

you could use generators,

```py
perm = [(i,j) for i in list[0] for j in list[1]]
```

furthermore if you could convert this into a generator object, if you memory concerns,

```py
perm = ((i,j) for i in list[0] for j in list[1]])
```

I was told you have n lists and want to permutate all of them,
you can use a while loop

```py
while(len(list)>1):
    a = list.pop()
    b = list.pop()
    list.append([(i, j) for i in a for j in b])
```

or make a recursive function. Do note, that the answer will be list[0] and not list itself.

Comment: actually I have a size n list with size c elements in each list. Then how can i apply your answer for it

Comment: @MadhushaniHewagama you could look at gph 's answer, it does exactly what I do, but recursively. it iterates over 2 lists first, then uses 1 of those with another list and so on.

Comment: @Blaine gph's answer is not recursive. It works with a size 2 list. For a solution to be recursive, a function must call itself (directly or indirectly).

Comment: I didnt go through that answer completely my apologies. Well what you could do is define a recursive function that pops two items from the lists, creates a list from my answer and appends it to that list until only one item is in the list. or you could use a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is with two functions

```
def funcA(x, arr):
  return [(x,c) for c in arr]

def funcB(arr1, arr2):
  ans = []
  for x in arr1:
    ans.extend(funcA(x, arr2))
  return ans
```

Call it whichever way to need:

```
funcB(your_list[0], your_list[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The most pythonic way is with itertools
you can simply use product from the itertools library like so:

```
my_list = [[a,b,c],[a,d,e]]
# will contain: [(a,a), (a,d)...]
all_combinations = list(itertools.product(*my_list))
```

The "*" unpacks the list into the lists it contains, its like writing:

```
# will contain: [(a,a), (a,d)...]
list(itertools.product([a,b,c],[a,d,e]))
```

It is worth mentioning that this works for any number of sublists.

```
my_list = [[a,b,c],[a,d,e], [1,2,3]]

# will contain: [(a,a,1), (a,a,2)...]
all_combinations = list(itertools.product(*my_list))
```

Hope that helps

Comment: question says explicitly without using an external library

Comment: yeah, Thank you, it's working. But I am finding way without using any external library

Answer (score 1):

```
l=[['a','b','c'],['a','d','e']]
def combinations(L, tmp=None):
    if tmp is None:
        tmp = []
    if L==[]:
        print (tmp)
    else:
        for i in L[0]:
            product(L[1:], tmp+[i])
combinations(l)
```

Does this help?